# Expression blend tutorials?

Tags: silverlight, video, blend

Hi Can anyone suggest the best video tutorials for learning expression blend?

Thanks Judi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have a [video series](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/cc197141.aspx) out at the Expression community site that you might want to check out. [Here's](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/cc136536.aspx) another. Heck, I would just recommend getting familiar with the community site ... there are a lot of goodies there, including the forums in the case you get stuck or have a question or two.

Also, a little outdated now, but I went through and really liked the free [lynda.com video series](http://www.lynda.com/home/DisplayCourse.aspx?lpk2=384) by Lee Brimelow. In fact, the overview of Silverlight talks about the original version of Silverlight, v1.0. Ha! Even given that, I still think you could get a lot of the series as a lot of the concepts would be the same.

[Total Training](http://www.totaltraining.com/prod/microsoft/expression.asp?utm_source=msft&utm_medium=inbox_dvd&utm_campaign=expression2) has some that you can pay for.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few to get you started:

http://www.silverzine.com

http://www.kirupa.com/blend_silverlight/index.htm

http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com

Hth, we could really use more Silverlight designers!